# Redirect all ips in config file to static address

Tags: python, flask, tornado, wsgi

Currently using Tornado as a wrapper for several WSGI apps (mostly Flask apps). Recently been noticing a lot of hacking attempts, and been wondering if it's possible to automatically look at a list of the IPs defined in some file and then redirect all of those IPs to a page saying something like "Someone using this IP tried hacking our site, prove you're not a bot and we'll re-allow your ip".

The tornado code that runs the server is here:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from Wrapper.app import application

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(application))
http_server.listen(80)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And wrapper.app is below:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from Splash import splash_app
from SentimentDemo import sentiment_app
from FERDemo import FER_app

application = DispatcherMiddleware(splash_app, {
    '/api/sentiment': sentiment_app,
    '/api/fer': FER_app
})
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this sort of thing, so I'm sorry in advance if this question seems uninformed, but even just a place to start looking would be spectacular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to subclass WSGIContainer and override its `__call__` method. Something like

```
class MyWSGIContainer(WSGIContainer):
    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.remote_ip in blacklist:
            self.write_redirect()
        else:
            super(MyWSGIContainer, self)(request)
```

For some tips on writing `self.write_redirect()` look at the code for the WSGIContainer [here](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/wsgi.py#L261); you can see how it formats the HTTP headers. You should use HTTP 302 Temporary Redirect.

Then pass your MyWSGIContainer instance into HTTPServer, instead of the default WSGIContainer.

Comment: Ah, Spectacular! Exactly what I was looking for.